# How to get Address internally In Google Map

Tags: google-maps

I know that we can fetch address from Google Map service if we append lat and long of particular location.

```
But My question is that is there any internal way or method that will fetch 
address detail on the base of given lat and long
```

If there is any method or way then help me plz,,i do not want to use webservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use geocoder. 
Through geocoder you can get location address.

Comment: But can i get address  without using URL?

Comment: using VS 2017 MVC, Google Map API geocoder returns value to [text area] tags properly when you have it properly initialized & set the value inside your custom geocoder function.